# How do I make a sprite rotate to follow my mouse in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an over the top shooter game and want my character to rotate to look at the mouse to use as an aim control, is there and easy way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first calculate the angle between your character sprite and the mouse cursor by the [Vector.AngleBetween](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599339(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your `update()`. After that, rotate your sprite by the angle calculated.